# How to get a num lock state using C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gtk, x11

I have read Gdk forum link which says that getting num lock state api is implemented since version 3.0. But I am using version 2.4 and I cannot update to version 3.0 as I need to support lower Linux version. Here is the discussion link:

http://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2010-July/msg00259.html

SO, is there any other way to get the num lock state using internal Linux command?

Regards,
iSight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the hard ware key code. Whenever num lock is on and pressed the number key at num pad i compare the hard ware key code which is universally constant to all manufacturer. Hence, I don't need to use ioctl.h header.

Answer (score 6):

Sample code to get the NumLock state. Let `foo.c` be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(void) {  
   Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(":0"); 
   XKeyboardState x;
   XGetKeyboardControl(dpy, &x);
   XCloseDisplay(dpy);
   printf("led_mask=%lx\n", x.led_mask);
   printf("NumLock is %s\n", (x.led_mask & 2) ? "On" : "Off");
   return 0;
}
```

Then this gives, tested with CentOS 5 on a Dell laptop:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo -lX11
foo
led_mask=2
NumLock is On
```

Or you could do something with `popen("xset q | grep LED");`.

The second bit of the mask is fairly common for NumLock, but I don't believe it is guaranteed.

**Original answer:** A good starting point is `xev`, available for about 20 years:

```
   xev
```

And you can decode key events via:

```
foobar (XKeyEvent *bar) {
   char dummy[20];
   KeySym key;
   KeySym keyKeypad;
   XLookupString(bar, dummy, sizeof dummy, &key, 0);
   keyKeypad = XKeycodeToKeysym(..., bar->keycode, NUMLOCK_Mask);
   if (IsKeypadKey(keyKeypad))
      ...;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: there's capslock and numlock states in that led_mask but not scrolllock state (I wonder if that key will still be present on our keyboards 50 years from now).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the Numlock state "while nothing is happening", and only when e.g. a keypress happens, the lowest overhead way is this.

For some `XKeyEvent *xke`

```
bool numlock = ((xke->state & Mod2Mask) == Mod2Mask);
```

For GDK, you might need something like [Gdk.FilterFunc](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gdk-3.0/Gdk.FilterFunc.html) to get the `xevent`. Check `xevent->type`.

```
#include <Xlib.h>
XEvent = (XEvent *) &xevent // from Gdk.FilterFunc
int type = event ->type;
switch(type) {
    case KeyPress:
    case KeyRelease:
        do_something_with((XKeyEvent *) event);
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did some sniffing around, and I found a possible implementation with `ioctl.h` that polls the keyboard state and tests that against a couple of flags.

[Take a look at this form post's implementation](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/176599-linux-c-num-lock-probdetect-and-toggle/page__p__1036341&#entry1036341), and replace `K_CAPSLOCK` with `K_NUMLOCK`*. It's pretty fugly, but it can easily be wrapped in a function and tucked away.

*The reason for the replacement on the post was because of an old bug where caps lock and num lock were accidentally reversed. [It should be fixed now](http://markmail.org/message/5w4fos2olfm2jkn6).

Comment: You don't want to do this in X - `/dev/tty0` probably won't be accessible due to permissions, and X probably has a command to get the modifier state

Answer (score -2):

You can use this linux command to do it

{
   if (num_lock == 0) system("setleds -F +num");
   else if num_lock == 1) ; //do nothing
}

Comment: What is the data type for num_lock and please let me know about its initialization

Comment: This is just a check flag in your program to know the state of numlock internally because with setleds you cannot take it. After it is set one time it won't try to enable it again.

Comment: I just need to check the state only, in that there should be some mechanism which will return the state in boolean or int data type.