# How to detect Caps Lock with ncurses?

Tags: c, ncurses

I need to detect that caps lock is turned on/off on c with ncurses. Is it possible? If yes, how to?

Googling this question gives nothing useful.

Update

The reason I'm looking for it is as follows: I need to handle such key combinations as alt+F and alt+shift+F with different handlers. But alt+F with caps lock and alt+shift+F without caps lock return the same key code (by `getch()`)

Comment: It's a good question, will definetelly look into this. If you give the reason to check it maybe we'll think of some workaround atm.

Comment: @zubergu I updated the question with reason.

Comment: What platform are you on? `getch`, using curses on my Mac terminal, returns `27/1Bh` and then `f`/`F` with and without Shift, but the same whether CapsLock is on or off.

Comment: I'm on debian7. Caps lock turns on shift when it's pressed and vice versa when not. I suppose there are other unix OSes with the same behavior.

Comment: In a TTY, you can use `ioctl` ("setleds" of the Debian package "console-tools" does so, for example) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427817) is an X11 solution. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. The state of Caps Lock is not made visible to terminals.

Comment: Is there another method besides ncurses?

Comment: You can't do this in a terminal application at all, no matter what you do it with.

Comment: I do hope you're wrong but reality says the opposite so far) Please comment/add answer if you find any workaround

Answer (score 3):

This can only be done with platform specific interface, i.e. using system interface rather than through the terminal/tty device. In Linux, you can read the keyboard device in /dev/input/ or by parsing the output of `xset -q`. Note that this will only be able to read local keyboard devices, which means that you won't be able to use this key if you need to use the program through ssh. You may need elevated permission to read input devices directly.